# Unable to access related model using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add User profile and my problem is I can't access my related model.

What I want is to add another information for the user. In using tinker I can add the profile. Here's what I did in tinker:

```
$user = new App\User;
$user->username = 'sampleusername';
$user->name = 'Bruce Lee';
$user->email = 'brucelee@sample.com';
$user->password = bcrypt('password');
$user->save();

$profile = new App\UserProfile;
$profile->phone = '123456789';
$profile->address = 'unknown';
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

By this approach I am able to add additional information but when I modified the **RegisterController**

I got this error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App\UserProfile' not found
```

Here's what I modified:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name'      =>  title_case($data['lastname']) . ' ' . title_case($data['firstname']),
            'username'  =>  $data['username'],
            'email'     =>  $data['email'],
            'password'  =>  bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        if($user) {

            $profile = new App\UserProfile;
            $profile->phone = $data['phone'];
            $profile->address = $data['address'];

            $user->profile()->save($profile);

            return $user;

        }

    }
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use full namespace. You can add `use` clause to the top of the controller:

```
use App\User;
```

Or you can use full namespace:

```
App\User::create();
```

**Update**

In the comments, you've asked about creating a user. Do this:

```
$user = User::create([
        'name'      =>  title_case($data['lastname']) . ' ' . title_case($data['firstname']),
        'username'  =>  $data['username'],
        'email'     =>  $data['email'],
        'password'  =>  bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

$user->profile()->create(['phone' => $data['phone'], 'address' => $data['address']]);

return $user;
```

Comment: Is it the RegisterController? Or if no, I haven't created any controller for my user profile

Comment: I modified my RegisterController to this:

`$profile = UserProfile::create([
                'user_id'   =>  $data->id,
                'phone'     =>  $data['phone'],
                'address'   =>  $data['address']
            ]);

            $user->profile()->save($profile);

            return $user;`

Comment: But I got this error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Thanks, It saved now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to add :`use App\User;` right after the current controller's namespace.

In the end you should have something like:

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App;
use App\User; <- this
class UserProfile{...}`

By default php tries to resolve the class in the current namespace

Comment: Ok ill try that

Comment: By the way I haven't created any controller for the User Profile. What I just did only is a model

Comment: The error is within the namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App` as the error points out

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this:

```
$profile = new \App\UserProfile;
$profile->phone = $data['phone'];
$profile->address = $data['address'];

$user->profile()->save($profile);

return $user;
```

Or after `namespace` in your php controller file, add this: `use App\User;` and `use App\UserProfile`. Then you will be able to use `User` and `UserProfile` without `App` namespace in your code.